# c# - Office 2016 interop dlls

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office, powerpoint

Office used to provide interop dlls that would allow developers to control office applications from c# code. For instance, advance a powerpoint presentation from an external application.

here is an example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/how-to-automate-control-23cd2a8f

I was wondering if this is still possible in Office 2016. I can't seem to find the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll or similar anywhere in my computer. They used to be found in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX".

Thanks in advance,

Pol